# HTML Nested Table won't re-size to cell height

Tags: html, css

This should be really simple, but for some reason I can't seem to get it to work!!

The table below is generated at runtime via Javascript (Python / Flask back end) and that all works fine, so I've just taken a couple of rows of the HTML generated to highlight the exact problem.

Having tweaked the formatting, I'm nearly where I want to be, but there are 2 issues that I can't seem to resolve:

1. Some cells don't resize to fit when the cell height is greater than the text (e.g. the table that goes from bet_id -> status and also back_price_size and lay_price_size).
2. The CSS 'chess board' pattern works most of the time, but oddly some rows in the table from bet_id -> status don't take the formatting, others do (this is a separate point, so I'm only mentioning in case its a quick fix, I can re-post as a separate question if this isn't appropriate).

I presume 1) at least is very simple, but whenever I include a style='height=100px;' or variation of it doesn't do what I assume it does.

The desired behaviour for the fields mentioned above, is that if the cell is higher (i.e. because another cell has more text, word-break is set to break-word) then these cells re-size to fit, otherwise the colours and borders look weird!

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<body>

<style>

:root {
  --border_colour: #e6b800;
  --back_colour_1: #0d0d26;
  --text_colour_1: #ff9900;
  --back_colour_2: #1a1a1a;
  --text_colour_2: #ffbf00;
}

body {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
font-size:12px;
overflow-x: hidden;
}

.divTable {
  table-layout: fixed;
  display: table;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid var(--border_colour);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding 3px;
  margin 3px;
  border-style: hidden;
  height=100%;
}

.divTableHeading
{
display: table-header-group;
  border: 1px solid var(--border_colour);
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

.divTableBody
{
display: table-row-group; 
  border: 1px solid var(--border_colour);
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

.divTableRow 
{
display: table-row; 
  border: 1px solid var(--border_colour);
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

.divTableHead {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid var(--border_colour);
    border-collapse: collapse;
    

}

.divTableCell {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid var(--border_colour);
    border-collapse: collapse;  
}

.divTableHead:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: var(--back_colour_2);
    color: var(--text_colour_2);
}
.divTableHead:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: var(--back_colour_1);
    color: var(--text_colour_1);
}

.divTableRow:nth-child(odd) .divTableCell:nth-child(odd), .divTableRow:nth-child(even), .divTableCell:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: var(--back_colour_1);
    color: var(--text_colour_1);
    word-break:break-all;
}

.divTableRow:nth-child(odd) .divTableCell:nth-child(even), .divTableRow:nth-child(even) .divTableCell:nth-child(odd)  {
        background-color: var(--back_colour_2);
    color: var(--text_colour_2);
    word-break:break-all;
}


</style>

<div id="market">
    <div class="divTable">
        <div class="divTableBody">
            </div>
            <div class="divTable">
                <div class="divTableHeading">
                    <div class="divTableRow">
                        <div class="divTableHead" style="width: 500px;">
                            <div>
                                <div class="divTable" style="height=100% !important">
                                    <div class="divTableHeading">
                                        <div class="divTableRow">
                                            <div class="divTableHead">
                                                <div>id</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="divTableHead">
                                                <div>status</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="divTableHead" style="width: 7%;">
                            <div>price_size</div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="divTableBody">
                    <div class="divTableRow">
                        <div class="divTableCell" style="height: 100% !important;">
                            <div style="height: 100% !important;">
                                <div class="divTable" style="height: 100% !important;">
                                    <div class="divTableBody" style="height: 100% !important;">
                                        <div class="divTableRow" style="height: 100% !important;">
                                            <div class="divTableCell">
                                                <div>123</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="divTableCell">
                                                <div>EXECUTABLE</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="divTableRow">
                                            <div class="divTableCell">
                                                <div>567</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="divTableCell">
                                                <div>EXECUTION_COMPLETE</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="divTableCell">
                            <div>
                                <div class="divTable">
                                    <div class="divTableBody" style="height=100%;">
                                        <div class="divTableRow">
                                            <div class="divTableCell"
                                                 style="background-color: #389cc7; color: white;  font-size:1em; border-style: hidden;">
                                                14.5
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="divTableRow" >
                                            <div class="divTableCell"
                                                 style="background-color: #389cc7; color: white;  font-size:0.75em; border-style: hidden;">
                                                4
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="divTableRow">
                        <div class="divTableCell">
                            <div style="height: 100% !important;">
                                <div class="divTable">
                                    <div class="divTableBody">
                                        <div class="divTableRow">
                                            <div class="divTableCell">
                                                <div>19440</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="divTableCell">
                                                <div>EXECUTION_COMPLETE</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="divTableCell">
                            <div>
                                <div class="divTable">
                                    <div class="divTableBody">
                                        <div class="divTableRow">
                                            <div class="divTableCell"
                                                 style="background-color: #389cc7; color: white;  font-size:1em; border-style: hidden;">
                                                10.5
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="divTableRow">
                                            <div class="divTableCell"
                                                 style="background-color: #389cc7; color: white;  font-size:0.75em; border-style: hidden;">
                                                3.94
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body></html>
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<style>

:root {
  --border_colour: #e6b800;
  --back_colour_1: #0d0d26;
  --text_colour_1: #ff9900;
  --back_colour_2: #1a1a1a;
  --text_colour_2: #ffbf00;
}

body {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
font-size:12px;
overflow-x: hidden;
}

.divTable {
  table-layout: fixed;
  display: table;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid var(--border_colour);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding 3px;
  margin 3px;
  border-style: hidden;
  height=100%;
}

.divTableHeading
{
display: table-header-group;
  border: 1px solid var(--border_colour);
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

.divTableBody
{
display: table-row-group; 
  border: 1px solid var(--border_colour);
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

.divTableRow 
{
display: table-row; 
  border: 1px solid var(--border_colour);
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

.divTableHead {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid var(--border_colour);
    border-collapse: collapse;
    

}

.divTableCell {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid var(--border_colour);
    border-collapse: collapse;  
}

.divTableHead:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: var(--back_colour_2);
    color: var(--text_colour_2);
}
.divTableHead:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: var(--back_colour_1);
    color: var(--text_colour_1);
}

.divTableRow:nth-child(odd) .divTableCell:nth-child(odd), .divTableRow:nth-child(even), .divTableCell:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: var(--back_colour_1);
    color: var(--text_colour_1);
    word-break:break-all;
}

.divTableRow:nth-child(odd) .divTableCell:nth-child(even), .divTableRow:nth-child(even) .divTableCell:nth-child(odd)  {
        background-color: var(--back_colour_2);
    color: var(--text_colour_2);
    word-break:break-all;
}


</style>

<div id="market">
    <div class="divTable">
        <div class="divTableBody">
            </div>
            <div class="divTable">
                <div class="divTableHeading">
                    <div class="divTableRow">
                        <div class="divTableHead" style="width: 500px;">
                            <div>
                                <div class="divTable" style="height=100% !important">
                                    <div class="divTableHeading">
                                        <div class="divTableRow">
                                            <div class="divTableHead">
                                                <div>id</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="divTableHead">
                                                <div>status</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="divTableHead" style="width: 7%;">
                            <div>price_size</div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="divTableBody">
                    <div class="divTableRow">
                        <div class="divTableCell" style="height: 100% !important;">
                            <div style="height: 100% !important;">
                                <div class="divTable" style="height: 100% !important;">
                                    <div class="divTableBody" style="height: 100% !important;">
                                        <div class="divTableRow" style="height: 100% !important;">
                                            <div class="divTableCell">
                                                <div>123</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="divTableCell">
                                                <div>EXECUTABLE</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="divTableRow">
                                            <div class="divTableCell">
                                                <div>567</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="divTableCell">
                                                <div>EXECUTION_COMPLETE</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="divTableCell">
                            <div>
                                <div class="divTable">
                                    <div class="divTableBody" style="height=100%;">
                                        <div class="divTableRow">
                                            <div class="divTableCell"
                                                 style="background-color: #389cc7; color: white;  font-size:1em; border-style: hidden;">
                                                14.5
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="divTableRow" >
                                            <div class="divTableCell"
                                                 style="background-color: #389cc7; color: white;  font-size:0.75em; border-style: hidden;">
                                                4
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="divTableRow">
                        <div class="divTableCell">
                            <div style="height: 100% !important;">
                                <div class="divTable">
                                    <div class="divTableBody">
                                        <div class="divTableRow">
                                            <div class="divTableCell">
                                                <div>19440</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="divTableCell">
                                                <div>EXECUTION_COMPLETE</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="divTableCell">
                            <div>
                                <div class="divTable">
                                    <div class="divTableBody">
                                        <div class="divTableRow">
                                            <div class="divTableCell"
                                                 style="background-color: #389cc7; color: white;  font-size:1em; border-style: hidden;">
                                                10.5
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="divTableRow">
                                            <div class="divTableCell"
                                                 style="background-color: #389cc7; color: white;  font-size:0.75em; border-style: hidden;">
                                                3.94
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body></html>
```

Comment: Can you use a code snippet to show us the problem

Comment: @ItsFragilis I've managed to condense the code and add a snippet finally!

Hopefully now it makes more sense. In the example (at least for me), the first price_size row contains nesting and I can't seem to get the nested cell to take up 100% of the parent cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the solution as follows?

[image]

If not then you can let me know. so, will check again and come up with other solution.

If yes, then you can achieve by doing following things:

1. First you need to search from the html or wherever you are setting your height attribute. Because in some cases its like

> height=100%

which will not work. So, you can search in above your given html text you will find it at three places. First you can correct as follows:

> height:100%

2. As per your given html there is extra div generating for the price_size column child table. Which is the main cause for preventing to make height of the child table to 100%. By removing that anonymous div, you will get the 100% height of the child table. You can check in following image the extra div in between `<div class="divTableCell">` and `<div class="divTable">`:

[image]

Comment: So simple!!!

Oddly I can't remember why I put that <div> in there, there was originally a reason, but I can't remember it now so I will remove as you suggest and those syntax errors are careless so have corrected them too and it all works!

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Consider ***massively*** simplifying your html structure and using a regular html `table` element that has all the functionality you need, but without any of the butchering required.

It is also semantic and is literally built for what you are doing.

<sup>I'm sorry if you have to use the div style markup you have provided. I'm happy to remove this answer if it doesn't answer your question.</sup>

```css
table{
  background: black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
td, th{
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}

.highlight{
  background: #389cc7;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        id
      </th>
      <th>
        status
      </th>
      <th>price_size</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>123</td>
      <td>EXECUTABLE</td>
      <td class="highlight">
        14.5<br/>
        4
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do have to use the div structure as opposed to table, however the exact structure of the div's can be changed, so if this particular nesting approach is flawed I can amend that.

That aside, I am still curious as to what is blocking my code from working (even if its not the most efficient approach).